# How to upgrade Jenkins Server cartridge (OpenShift)?

Tags: jenkins, openshift, upgrade

How to upgrade Jenkins Server cartridge (openshift) to latest version, please?

Answer (score 2):

It can be done by getting the latest war file and pointing an environment variable(JENKINS_WAR_PATH) to the new one.

More info [here](https://github.com/openshift/jenkins-cloud-plugin/issues/27)

Comment: Why the downvotes. This is literally the correct answer. I even upgraded jenkins myself.

Comment: +1, this is correct as mentioned on [github](https://github.com/openshift/jenkins-cloud-plugin/issues/27#issuecomment-41483911) issue page. worked for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late, but here is the correct steps for upgrading Jenkins in Openshift manually.

1. Install rhc tools from openshift and configure it to your account.
2. Run `rhc set-env JENKINS_WAR_PATH=/path -a your_app_name` from terminal.

   Eg : `rhc set-env JENKINS_WAR_PATH=/var/lib/openshift/585fdddb2d5271c8bc000109/app-root/data/jenkins_war/jenkins.war -a jenkins`
3. Restrat your app from openshift console.

Read more at : https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1099252

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick note that `rhc` is for OpenShift 2. If you are using OpenShift 3, you'll need the `oc` binary.